# Kotlin - Trying to factorize code with high-order function

Tags: kotlin

I'm quite new to Kotlin and I'd like to see if using high-order functions can help in my case.

My use-case is that I need to call the methods of an IInterface derived class to send events to one or more components. And I'd like to make this generic, and I want to check if a high-order funtion can help. A sample of code will help to understand (well, I hope so!).

```
private val eventListeners = mutableListOf<IEventInterface>() // List filled somewhere else!

private fun sendConnectionEvent(dummyString: String) {
    val deadListeners = mutableListOf<IEventInterface>()

    eventListeners.forEach {
        try {
            it.onConnectionEvent(dummyString)
        } catch (e: DeadObjectException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Removing listener - Exception ${e.message}")
            deadListeners.add(it)
        }
    }

    deadListeners.forEach { it ->
        eventListeners.remove(it)
    }
}

private fun sendWonderfulEvent(dummyString: String, dummyInt: Int) {
    val deadListeners = mutableListOf<IEventInterface>()

    eventListeners.forEach {
        try {
            it.onWonderfulEvent(dummyString, dummyInt)
        } catch (e: DeadObjectException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Removing listener - Exception ${e.message}")
            deadListeners.add(it)
        }
    }

    deadListeners.forEach { it ->
        eventListeners.remove(it)
    }
}
```

I added 2 similar methods (I will have many more in the real use case) and I think (I hope!) that something could be done but I can't make high-order function works in this case because:

- I want to call the same **method** on several **instances**, and not 'just' a basic function
- To make things even worse, the methods I need to call don't have the same prototype (that would have been too easy!).

Hope this is clear enough.

Thanks for your help!

VR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can be done

```
fun onEvent(body: (IEventInterface) -> Unit) {
    val deadListeners = mutableListOf<IEventInterface>()
    eventListeners.forEach {
        try {
            body(it)
        } catch (ex: DeadObjectException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Removing listener - Exception ${e.message}")
            deadListeners.add(it)
        }
    }

    deadListeners.forEach { it ->
        eventListeners.remove(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Supposing an interface like this:

  ```
  interface IEventInterface {
      fun onConnectionEvent(dummyString: String)
      fun onWonderfulEvent(dummyString: String, dummyInt: Int)
  }
  ```
- Define an generic type that implements your defined interface ( `<T : IEventInterface>`)
- Define an mutable list of this type to receive your implementation  (`MutableList<T>.removeIfThrows`)
- Expect an extension function for you type that will do your specific validation (and custom parameters if you want)
- Using an apply and returning the instance you can run your code like a pipeline
- Executing the custom validation when you want

  ```
  private fun <T : IEventInterface> MutableList<T>.removeIfThrows(validation: T.() -> Unit, customLogMessage: String? = null): MutableList<T> {
      return apply {
          removeIf {
              it.runCatching {
                  validation()
              }.onFailure { error ->
                  print(customLogMessage ?: "Removing listener - Exception ${error.message}")
              }.isFailure
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Define your specific implementation passing just the function with custom validation as an parameter

  ```
  private fun <T : IEventInterface> MutableList<T>.sendConnectionEvent(dummyString: String) = removeIfThrows({
      onConnectionEvent(dummyString)
  })

  private fun <T : IEventInterface> MutableList<T>.sendWonderfulEvent(dummyString: String, dummyInt: Int) = removeIfThrows({
      onWonderfulEvent(dummyString, dummyInt)
  })
  ```
- Now you can run your code like an pipeline modifying your original object like this

  ```
  private fun nowYouCanDoSomethingLikeThis() {
      eventListeners
              .sendConnectionEvent("some dummy string")
              .sendWonderfulEvent("some another dummy string", 123)
  }
  ```